# Making Application Available to the public

Tags: c#

I have been writing a personal application which a friend has expressed interest in and asked if I would give them a copy of it. The problem is, that this application relies heavily on a Database hosted on a remote cloud service. So, with best practices/Security and data integrity in mind, if I was to make this application available to the public (not just one or two friends) would it be in best practices to change the database mechanic in general? From:

> Connect to DB > Query DB > Return Result Set

To:

> Host ASP Site > Application CURLS Site > Site Connects & Queries
>   Database > Site Returns Result Set > Application works with the CURL
>   Response

Is this a secure way of making the data publicly available? If not, why? Are there more secure or less complex ways?

Comment: To Whom made the closed vote. Technically yes this an opinion based question, but the front of the question is security and data integrity. Asking this question is in my best interest not to expose Sensitive data unknowingly and compromise nodes

Comment: need a little more information on the nature of the data.  Is it read only?  is it a ton of data?

Comment: @Segfault It's a fractionally small database, including at the most 5 tables and 3 views with not that many rows inbetween. It's not a Read only Server, some writing in one or two tables with user input need to be handled, opening to the public would increase the tables demand on input/output overheads obviously

Comment: @DarylGill I reworded your question to be less opinionated. The question is now asking for more fact-based solutions. Please review it and make sure I've not changed the intent of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current industry best practice is to create a web service, preferably RESTful, and have your application communicate with that.

Comment: Will read into creating/maintaining and the pros of a Restful service, thank you

Comment: @DarylGill Often for heavy clients you can do this with [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation), but [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is gaining traction (due to simplicity) even among non-web based clients.

Comment: @mason Would a web service also include a socket server? to accept/handle requests? or would this fail if two incoming connections was recorded at the same time/

Comment: @DarylGill I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "socket server", perhaps you're thinking too low in the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). But web services can handle multiple concurrent connections without any issues (though if you have a ton of clients, you may run into scaling issues and need to scale up).

Comment: @DarylGill typically you do not include your own socket server for a web service, but leverage the web / http server of your choice, e.g. Apache, IIS, or nginx.